# fftw/c++ computes fft wrong, compared to matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, fftw

I am trying fftw with c++. I want to test that it works correct. I implemented a simple

```
ifft(fft(shift(data)) - data == 0
```

test, that fails completely.

The testdata is a rect function, with amplitude and phase 1. The matlab code for comparison works perfectly with the same test.

The basic question is: what am I doing wrong?

Here the matlab code (which is also using fftw...) FFTW dll/.h is latest.

```
data = zeros(1, 64);
halfsize = numel(data)/2;
data(halfsize-10:halfsize+10) = 1;

phase = ones(size(data));
data =  data.*exp(phase*sqrt(-1));

Ft = fft(fftshift(data));
```

[image: original data]
[image: fourier transform]

In C++ the code is (not complete)

```
std::vector<complex<double>,fftalloc<complex<double> > > data(N);
std::vector<complex<double>,fftalloc<complex<double> > > dataFourier(N);
... create data
int nfft = data.size();
fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(nfft,fftw_cast(&data[0]),fftw_cast(&dataFourier[0]), FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE|FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT);
fftw_execute(plan);
//fftw_execute_dft( plan, fftw_cast(&data[0]),fftw_cast(&dataFourier[0]));
cout << dataFourier[0] << dataFourier.back() << endl;
```

The output is completely different
[image: C++ plots]

The first complex value is completely different to the last

```
(59.8627,7.57324)(-4.00561,7.33222)
```

Whereas in matlab they are similar. Also the phase is completely different:

```
11.3463 +17.6709i  10.8411 +13.7128i
```

For higher N these values are the same (here N = 64)

Comment: Why are you using fftshift in the time domain? It is to be used in the frequency domain. I know it is a common fallacy, but that doesn't make it right. http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html Btw. Matlab internally uses FFTW to compute the DFT.

Comment: I also suggest that you probably center your rectangular function (halfsize-9:halfsize+10), and I would like to add that the rectangular function due to its discontinuities is not a proper function to be transformed via DFT.

Comment: @Ynpos: I use the shift because otherwise the phase in the f. domain is wrong.

Comment: @Ynpos: If I use in matlab ´data(halfsize-8:halfsize+10) = 1´ the phase is a recangular grating shape without a tilt. However the number of steps in matlab is still twice the count in c++. An most important. The magnitude is not modified by that. The m. is wrong in c++.

Comment: How do you decide what is right or wrong here? Can you update your results with the properly aligned rectangle? Remember: The Fourier transform expects a l² integratable periodic function. Why don't you start with such a function in your testing? If you need to shift in the time domain you are doing it wrong. `ifft(fft(shift(data)) - data == 0` should never be true, except if the shift matches the period.

Comment: Do you mean to align it in matlab or c++ different?. I could as well use any other function. You may recommend one. The thing that is obvious is that in matlab ifft(fft(data)) always gives back the original result, no matter how I align things. With c++ the forward ftt is resulting in unexpected data.

Answer (score 1):

FFTW and Matlab don't compute the same things.  From [the FFTW tutorial](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html#Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs):

> FFTW computes an unnormalized DFT. Thus, computing a forward followed
>   by a backward transform (or vice versa) results in the original array
>   scaled by `n`.  For the definition of the DFT, see [What FFTW Really
>   Computes](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/What-FFTW-Really-Computes.html#What-FFTW-Really-Computes).

Comment: I know but that has nothing to do with my problem posted here. The scaling is not my problem. The fft is wrong thus the ifft is wrong too.